# How to instantiate a shape type object in hacklang

Tags: hacklang

This seems like it should be in the documentation, but it isn't.

I have a shape type.

```
type ThisIsMyShapeType = shape(
  'some_prop' => bool,
);
```

How do I instantiate an object of this type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the same `shape` keyword:

```
$x = shape(
  'some_prop' => true,
);
```

In Hack, shapes use [structural typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) so you don't need to declare your variable is a `ThisIsMyShapeType` -- the typechecker will verify that `$x` has all of the right fields to match the type.

There are quite a few examples [in the official documentation](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/built-in-types/shape).